# Network Adapter IPv4 Alias not saving after computer restart?

Tags: save, ip, adapter, alias, restart

I'm trying to add a secondary IP to my network adapter (Radmin VPN, in this case).

I did this via CMD:

```
netsh -c Interface ip add address name="Radmin VPN" addr=26.134.144.112 mask=255.0.0.0
```

It works fine, I can see the alias if I go to the IPv4 properties and check it.

However, after I restart the computer, the alias disappears.

How can I make it permanent?